# passing a state hook to another element using props is not working in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have tow components one should have the states of showing and hiding an icon. the other should at least show that icon on click since the default state in not showing anything, so I am trying to pass down the showIcon function down to the other element using props but its not working showing an error showIcon is not a function

```js
//Component A Row
import anItem from './anItem';

function Row(props) {
    const [iconState, setIconState] = useState([]);
    const icon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fas", "check"]}/>
    // from anItem  component 
    const showIcon = ()=>{
    setIconState([icon])
    }
    // from this component
     const removeIcon = ()=>{
    setIconState([])
    }
    
    
    // Pass the funtion down to the below componant so we can hide the element from there 
    let item = [<anItem icon=iconState showIcon={showIcon}/>]
    
    return (
        <li className="day-row check faderin" onClick={()=> reomveIcon()}>
        // render all the items in the initial state 
        {item}
        </li>
    )
}

// Component B anItem 
function anItem(props) {
 return (
<div  onClick={() =>{props.showIcon}>{porps.icon}</div>
 )
}

export default anlItem
```

Comment: Typos?  It looks like you forgot the parenthese to call the function: `props.showIcon()` and in the JSX you have `porps.icon`.  You also didn't properly declare your `showIcon` and `removeIcon` functions, put the `const` or `let` keyword before them just like all your other declarations.  This also needs curly braces around the value: `icon=iconState`  The more I look at this code, the more typos I find...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I see some typo:

```
let item = [<anItem icon={iconState} showIcon={showIcon}/>] // add curly braces
```

Make sure you correctly define the functions below (with **const** keyword):

```
const showIcon = ()=> {
 setIconState([icon])
}

const removeIcon = ()=> {
 setIconState([])
}
```

I see also another problem in your **anItem** component:

```
function anItem(props) {
     return (
    <div  onClick={() => props.showIcon()}>{porps.icon}</div> // here onClick param
     )
    }
```

Or like this:

```
function anItem(props) {
 return (
<div  onClick={props.showIcon}>{porps.icon}</div> // here onClick param
 )
}
```